# Message is not dispatched into the thread in android

Tags: android

As part of my learning Android Threading, I have done the below code.

```
package simple.learning.com.samplethread;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyThread  myThread;
    Button button;

    private static class MyThread extends Thread {
        public Handler mHandler;

        public void run () {
            Log.d ("TESTME", " iNSIDE RUN..");
            Looper.prepare();
            mHandler = new Handler () {

              public void HandleMessage (Message msg) {
                  Log.d("TESTME", "iNSIDE HandleMessage");
                  if ( msg.what == 0) {
                      someWork();
                  }
              }
            };

            Looper.loop();

        }

        public void someWork()
        {
            while (true) {
                Log.d("TESTME", "Inside someWork ");
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myThread = new MyThread();
        myThread.start();


        Button btn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        assert btn != null;
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (myThread.mHandler != null) {
                    Log.d("TESTME", " bUTTON pRESSED..");
                    Message msg = myThread.mHandler.obtainMessage(0);
                    myThread.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I Click the button, I expect the msg to be posted into the message queue. But, I don't see any output displayed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the last log you saw?

Answer (score 1):

You made a small mistake in overriding the handleMessage, instead of overriding the real one you added some method. Below is the working solution:

```
private static class MyThread extends Thread {
    public Handler mHandler;

    public void run() {
        Log.d("TESTME", " iNSIDE RUN..");
        Looper.prepare();
        mHandler = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Log.d("TESTME", "iNSIDE HandleMessage");
                if (msg.what == 0) {
                    someWork();
                }
            }
        };

        Looper.loop();

    }

    public void someWork() {
        while (true) {
            Log.d("TESTME", "Inside someWork ");
        }
    }

}
```